# Flutter: Ads consent with google_mobile_ads

Tags: flutter, admob

Do you need to care about ads consent dialog (to ask users if they agree to see personalized ads) when using Flutter's google_mobile_ads package. Or may be this part is handled by the package itself?

Comment: Required on iOS, users may either choose to see personalised ads. There is also a different package for asking the same permission.

Comment: @DarShan Only on iOS and not on Android?

Comment: For Android, it might be required in the EU region due to GDPR afaik, there's also a separate Android side library for that.